# Tkinter window slightly off center

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()

width_value = master.winfo_screenwidth()
height_value = master.winfo_screenheight()
master.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (width_value, height_value))

mainloop()
```

[image]

Could someone please explain why I am constantly getting a small gap/window being off-centered? Also, a solution would be great thanks.

Comment: When this happens, are you able to interactively grab the titlebar with the mouse, and move the window further left?

Comment: @BryanOakley yes but it would be best if the user didn't have to do that every time the window gets opened

Comment: I understand. The thing I'm trying to verify is if the window is offset from the edge or if it only _appears_ to be offset from the edge. I don't use windows so I don't know Windows enforces a thin black border around the display.

Comment: It happens in Windows 10 only, not in Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, simply replace:

```
width_value = master.winfo_screenwidth()
height_value = master.winfo_screenheight()
master.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (width_value, height_value))
```

with:

```
master.state('zoomed')
```

This sets the tkinter window as full screen (while keeping the title bar)